# condition`s value is false but the program enters if

Tags: java, if-statement

i have a main class that implements `Runnable`. In my function I check if a specific button inside a panel was clicked. I have an if conditions but the program always enters the if, even if its values is false. I tried to switch the condition to `if(true==false)` and that's how I realized that it enters the if always.

The output is always false and inside if.

this is my run() function :

```
public void run()
{
    while (true)
    {
        System.out.println(categorys_list_panel.isMovetoErrorsList());
        if(categorys_list_panel.isMovetoErrorsList());
        {
            System.out.println("inside if");
            category = categorys_list_panel.getCategoryValue();
            categorys_list_panel.MovedToErrorList();
            try 
            {
                errors_list_panel.refresh(category);
            } 
            catch (SQLException e) 
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            //cardLayout.show(const_panel, "2");                
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You have a semicolon immediately after the `if` condition. There shouldn't be one there.

Comment: Funny i knew the answer by just reading the heading - common pitfall...

Comment: question should be closed because it's a simple typographical error

Comment: As @JonK said, `;` immediately after `if` instructs the program to do nothing if the condition is true. In java `{` and `}` mark code blocks, and can be used almost anywhere to group some statements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `if` statement is terminated by a semicolon (`;`), and a block that starts after it

```
if(categorys_list_panel.isMovetoErrorsList());
//                                 here -----^
{
```

This means that the condition is evaluated, and if it's `true` nothing is executed.
Then, an anonymous block is opened, executed, and closed.

In order to have the block relate to the `if`, you should remove the semicolon:

```
if(categorys_list_panel.isMovetoErrorsList()) // no ;
{
```

Comment: 'Then, an anonymous block is opened, executed, and closed'-+1

Comment: with your rep you should know that there is is a valid close reason, and no answer is required.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `;` at the end of your line `if(categorys_list_panel.isMovetoErrorsList());`

Answer (score 0):

The semicolon after the `if` is saying the statement ends there...

```
    if(categorys_list_panel.isMovetoErrorsList())
```